# svnx is not showing path section and also resolve is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, svn, svnx

I am facing following 2 issues while using SVN.

1. When opens the Repository -> it is not showing paths sections.
   Attached the screen shot.
2. When i get the conflict in any file, i click on resolve -> but it is not opening my diff merge. It shows me alert.

[image]

Please let me know how to resolve these 2 issues. Thankz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click GEAR ICON in the right of SEARCH MESSAGES

[image]